# App only shows one cell (one song) as opposed to all of them

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

im currently writing an app but can't figure out how to translate this particular Objective-C line into swift. Any help will be much appreciated. I've been able to translate other lines just fine but this one throws some exception error. Here's the original Objective-C line:

> MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

I'm a noob and have tried many variations including:

> var rowItem = songs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as MPMediaItem

and

> var rowItem: MPMediaItem = songs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as MPMediaItem

But I've been at this so long I can't see what it should be. Many thanks!

edit:

songs is defined as:

> let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
>   let songs = [songsQuery.items] as NSArray

i just receive an exe_breakpoint error. I can get past this if i encapsulate the MPMediaItem in an array by using ... as [MPMediaItem] but then i can't get the property values e.g. MPMediaItemPropertyTitle and MPMediaItemPropertyArtist.

update:
managed to get it working by using a for loop to obtain the MPMediaItemPropertyTitle and MPMediaPropertyArtist. The 'songs' variable is defined as i have written above. @Antonio, removing the brackets did not work. This is my current code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    let allSongsArray = [songsQuery.items] as NSArray

    var singleItem: AnyObject = allSongsArray[indexPath.row]

    var rowItem = singleItem as [MPMediaItem]

    if rowItem.count > 0 {

        cell.textLabel?.text = rowItem[0].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowItem[0].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as NSString
    }

    return cell
}
```

The problem i have now is when i test the app, it only displays the very first song in my library and does not list every song like it is supposed to. Thank you for any help you can provide!

UPDATE 2:

Got it working with the following code:

```
class SongsViewController: UITableViewController {

var allSongs : [MPMediaItem] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    allSongs += MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items as [MPMediaItem]
    println(allSongs.count)

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return allSongs.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    var rowItem = allSongs[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as NSString

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should provide more details - how is `songs` defined? What kind of error you have? Compilation or runtime? What's the error message?

Comment: why those square brackets '[songsQuery.items]'?? what is the data type of  items property?

Comment: Is there any meaningful error message in the exception? Have you checked that the index actually exists?

Comment: Try changing `let songs = [songsQuery.items] as NSArray` to `let songs = songsQuery.items as NSArray` (if it works I'll explain)

Comment: @Shoaib the data types of the items in the array are objects

Comment: @Antonio nope that didn't work but i managed to sort that problem but have immediately come across another issue that's detailed in the update in the original post.

Comment: @air6199: since your last update is the actual solution to the problem (which is very similar to mine :)), I think it would be better if you move it to an answer and accept it as the solution - it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allSongs : [MPMediaItem] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

allSongs += MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items as [MPMediaItem]
println(allSongs.count)

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return allSongs.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

var rowItem = allSongs[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as NSString

return cell
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
let allSongsArray = [songsQuery.items] as NSArray
```

Here you take an `Array<AnyObject>!` and wrap it in another `Array` which you then cast to an NSArray... quite a mess.

Try this:

```
let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
let allSongs = songsQuery.items as [MPMediaItem]
let song = allSongs[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.text = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as String
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as String
```

Also, you really should cache `allSongs` instead of querying it every time you need to populate a cell. To do this, simply create add a `var allSongs: [MPMediaItem] = []` to your controller. Then in for example `viewDidLoad` use a MPMediaQuery to populate that array. You can then use that array in any of the table view delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: nope, that didn't work. "Array index out of range" for the line let song: AnyObject = ... (also i assumed allSongsArray is supposed to be allSongs) how would i go about caching the songs list?

Comment: Ok, so the number of rows in your table is probably not the same as the number of items in `allSongs`. What does your numberOfRowsInSection... method do? (you were correct about `allSongsArray`, I fixed it)

Comment: it carries out a songsQuery and puts them into an array (same method as first two lines of code posted) and then it returns allSongsArray.count

Comment: Hmm, weird. I suggest you first work on 'caching' the songs. A lot of future problems, perhaps this one as well, will then probably disappear. I added a little bit about this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give that a go, that somewhat makes sense to me.

Comment: i've attempted to use the 'caching' method and have uploaded the code to the original post. All the songs work now! Many thanks for your suggestion, please can you have a look if i did actually do it correctly/efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you're making is loading the entire data source in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, whereas that should be done in another place (`viewDidLoad` being a good candidate), and most important once and not for every row.

I've reworked on your code, and I've come up with this code:

```
class TestViewController : UITableViewController {
    var allSongsArray: [MPMediaItem]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
        self.allSongsArray = songsQuery.items as [MPMediaItem]

        // Other initializations
        ...
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.allSongsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var rowItem = self.allSongsArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = rowItem[0].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowItem[0].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as NSString

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: managed to get mine working about 10 seconds before you posted this! i'll post the relevant code in the main post, please can you have a look if i've stored/loaded the data in the correct place?

Comment: @air6199 your code seems good, and actually mine looks like a photocopy of yours ;-)